# Is it possible to translate pseudo element as css content with React Intl?

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, translation, pseudo-element, react-intl

I need some help. I'm new to React and I'm trying to translate app with ReactIntl and FormattedMessage. My question is: "Can I translate content of css pseudo element ::before, that is located in my App.css file?" And if it's possible, how? :-)

```
    .btnAdd::before {
  content: "Add";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible. but you can define different classes and pass them dynamically using intl

Comment: What you have in mind? How to do that?

Comment: did you manage to solve this ? @Danijela_

Comment: You need to use styled-component package. Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components

Answer (score 0):

A great way is to use html's lang attribute! 
Like this:

```
html[lang="en"] .btnAdd:before {
    content: 'Add';
}
html[lang="pl"] .btnAdd:before {
    content: 'Dodaj';
}
html[lang="it"] .btnAdd:before {
    content: 'Aggiungi';
}
```